# Where is Capistrano 3's `deploy:cold` defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Capistrano on the whole is a very useful tool, but the definitions are so modular and distributed it can be difficult (or near impossible) to find the definition of a task when needed, or easily piece together the order of events.

I had only vaguely worked with Capistrano before v3, and I recall there being a "cold deploy" task.

However, I can't seem to find it anywhere within the capistrano repository, nor within any of the plugins (`capistrano/rvm`, `capistrano/bundler`, `capistrano/rails`, etc...). A [simple repository search for the term 'cold' yields nothing](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cold)

Where is this task defined? Does it exist in Capistrano v3? And is there an easy way to visualize all the tasks, in order, that run when I execute a certain command (e.g. `bundle exec cap production deploy` would list all 10,000+ deploy tasks)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

actually there's no such task in capistrano 3.
You can see all task with command:

```
cap -T
```

for deploying i usually start with

```
cap production setup # Server setup tasks
cap production deploy:check # Check required files and directories exist
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such task like `deploy:cold` in `capistrano 3` rather you can use the following command for the same thing

```
bundle exec cap production deploy setup
```

You can read the task definition in the lib files located in

```
lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake
```